# Remove spaces using regex preg_match php field validation

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to filter "name" field to accept just one space between words or numbers.

I tried:

```
    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+(  [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/u', $alias)) {
     $contr->setData('errorField('.$field.')', 'Just one space per word.');

        return false;
    }
```

... this works but, it's not what i'm looking for, cause it throws an error on typing "Mark"

I need a regex preg_match to detect any unecesary whitespace, something like:

- Case 1: Mark -> Simply as that, returns OK
- Case 2. Mark **[one space]** Anthony -> OK
- Case 3. Mark **[two spaces or more]** Anthony -> NOT OK contains 2 white spaces
- Case 4. Mark **[one space]** Anthony **[one space]** Monroy -> OK
- Case 5. Mark **[one space]** Anthony **[two spaces or more]** Monroy -> NOT OK contains 2 white spaces after "Anthony"

... The name field should accept numbers as well, like:

Mark 200 -> Mark Anthony 200 etc...

Comment: Do you want to convert multiple spaces to one space? If so, you might use `preg_replace('~\s{1,}~', ' ', $your_string);`

Comment: `preg_match('/\s{2}/')` ??? To remove use `\s{2,}` with `preg_replace`.

Comment: negate the condition and use only one space: `if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/', $alias)) {`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern could be:

'#^(?:[\w-]+ ?)*$#'

Answer (score 0):

[@Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) posted the solution. The correct preg_match in this case is:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/u', $alias)) {
         $contr->setData('errorField('.$field.')', 'Just one space per word.');

            return false;
        }
```

So simple as adding !preg_match ... 
Thanks

Comment: Since you only deal with ASCII character, you don't need to add the u modifier. You can also change your capturing group to a non-capturing group and use the i modifier to reduce the code size.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/IZ1hTr/1)

```
 {2,}
```

**Note**: Regex above has a space character at the beginning (it's not just `{2,}`). It's simply matching 2 or more space characters.

#### Replacement

This method replaces 2+ spaces with one space.

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/ewo3gl)

```
$re = '/ {2,}/';
$names = [
    'Mark',
    'Mark Anthony',
    'Mark Anthony Monroe',
    'Mark  Anthony',
    'Mark Anthony  Monroy'
];

foreach($names as $name) {
    echo preg_replace($re, ' ', $name)."\n";
}
```

#### Match

This method simply recognizes 2+ spaces.

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/adUOGj)

```
$re = '/ {2,}/';
$names = [
    'Mark',
    'Mark Anthony',
    'Mark Anthony Monroe',
    'Mark  Anthony',
    'Mark Anthony  Monroy'
];

foreach($names as $name) {
    if(preg_match($re, $name)) {
        echo $name."\n";
    }
}
```